# Matching DSCP portion of ToS or traffic class byte using ebtables

Tags: linux, firewall, netfilter

Is it possible to match only the DSCP portion of the IPv4 ToS or IPv6 traffic class byte using `ebtables`? I see that `ebtables` has the `--ip-tos` match option for IPv4 packets and the `--ip6-class` match option for IPv6 packets. To my understanding, those match the entire ToS or traffic class byte (i.e. the 6 DSCP bits and 2 ECN bits). To match DSCP specifically and ignore ECN bits, whatever they may be set to, I'd think a bitwise `&` would work, e.g. `ToS byte of packet & 0xAC` would match DSCP field `0x2B` (`0xAC` being `0x2B << 2`), but I don't think bitmasking is possible with the ebtables `--ip-tos` and `--ip6-class` options.

Is it possible to match only the DSCP portion with `ebtables`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't convert everything to *nftables* instead (where such mask is part of the generic language but anyway not needed since there's a specific keyword for this)? Telling this because I don't think such mask exists for ebtables.

Comment: @A.B legacy project that uses eb/iptables, but sounds like it's time to migrate to `nft`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, it doesn't seem that this is possible with `ebtables` (thank you for the comment @A.B), as there's no mask or specific keyword for `dscp`. Trying this in a legacy project that uses `eb/iptables`, but going to migrate to `nft` as there's a built-in `dscp` keyword that should work at the bridge layer.

Comment: AFAIK ebtables (legacy) features' support is almost complete except for 1/ no string match (same for iptables' string match) 2/ broute requires recent nftables and kernel 3/ not really a 3, but while checking dscp here I noticed that `etables-translate` translates incorrectly --ip6-tclass' value into its dscp equivalent, and --ip-tos requires manual adaptation. For both cases dscp is to be used of course.